# How to create a score multiplier?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a making an endless skiing game, and already have a scoring system, however i want to add a score multiplier based on the number of consecutive tricks done without touching the ground. here's my script so far:

```
public class tricksScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float flips = 0;
    private float deltaRotation = 0;
    private float currentRotation = 0;
    private float WindupRotation = 0;
    public static Rigidbody2D rigbod;
    public Text scores;
    private int trickscore;
    private int iflip;
    private int oldscore;
    private int incInScore;
    public float speed;
    private float counter;
    private int flipscore;
    private int rockDestroy;
    private bool grounded;
    private int multiplier = 1;
    // Collision2D coll;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speed = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>().speed;
        scores = GameObject.Find("score").GetComponent<Text>();
        rigbod = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        grounded = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>().grounded;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rigbod.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rigbod.velocity.y);
        deltaRotation = currentRotation - rigbod.transform.eulerAngles.z;
        currentRotation = rigbod.transform.eulerAngles.z;
        if (deltaRotation >= 300) deltaRotation -= 360;
        if (deltaRotation <= -300) deltaRotation += 360;
        WindupRotation += (deltaRotation);
        flips = WindupRotation / 340;
        iflip = (int)flips;
        iflip = iflip * -1;
        flipscore = iflip * 10;
        trickscore = flipscore + rockDestroy;
        scores.text = "score " + (trickscore * multiplier);
        incInScore = trickscore - oldscore;
        if (incInScore >= 10)
        {
            oldscore = trickscore;
        }
        
        //speed += (Mathf.Round(incInScore)) / 100.0f;
      
        if (incInScore > 1 && incInScore <= 10)
        {
            speed = speed + 0.15f;
            counter += 3f;
        }
        if (incInScore > 10 && incInScore <= 20)
        {
            speed = speed + 0.25f;
            counter += 3f;
        }
        if (incInScore > 20 && incInScore <= 50)
        {
            speed = speed + 0.50f;
            counter += 3f;
        }
        if (incInScore > 50 && incInScore <= 100)
        {
            speed = speed + 0.75f;
            counter += 3f;
        }
        if (incInScore > 100 && incInScore <= 200)
        {
            speed = speed + 1f;
            counter += 3.5f;
        }
        if (incInScore > 200)
        {
            speed = speed + 2f;
            counter += 4f;
        }

        if (incInScore > 5 && grounded == false)
        {
            multiplier = multiplier + 1;
        } 
        else if (grounded == true)
        {
            multiplier = 1;
        }

        if (speed > 5.15f)
        {
            speed -= 0.05f * Time.deltaTime;
        } 
        else if (speed == 5.15f)
        {
            speed = 5.15f;
        }
         
        counter -= 1.0f * Time.deltaTime;
 
        if (counter < 0)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }

        if (incInScore >= 10)
        {
            incInScore = 0;             
        }

        if (incInScore < 0)
        {
            incInScore = incInScore * -1;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        //counter = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<tricksScore>().counter;
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            if (coll.collider.tag == "rock")
            {
                Destroy(coll.gameObject);
                speed = speed + 0.15f;
                rockDestroy = rockDestroy + 5;
                counter = counter + 2f;
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

I know the scripts dirty, but hopefully its still comprehensible for you all. thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It looks like you already have a score multiplier. Can you explain a bit about what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your ground boolean is only set in start, so it will almost always be false. Add the check statement in the update function, as when you set a variable with this property, it will only take the value at that time, it will not automatically update.

Comment: the multiplier i have created doesnt work. "counter" is like a boost thing here, i dont think it effects the working of the multplier

Comment: Relooked and saw grounded is only set in the start.

Comment: You would have to add `grounded = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>().grounded;` into the update function. When you assign grounded at the start, it will **not** change with the player control(basically it takes the value at the start of the script, and it will not change). Im guessing that your character starts on the ground, which will cause `grounded = false;`, which will never run your multiplier. If you put it in the update function, it will reasign/update grounded per each frame.

Comment: you fixed my problem 50%. now the score is increasing, but instead of becoming 40 for 2 backflips, its becoming 2000

Comment: Try logging both the multiplier and iflip values. My best guess would be that the multiplier is being increased incorrectly. Try setting the `incInScore` to 0 after each update(if that does not break your code).

Comment: inc in score is already being resetted to 0 =, u can see in the code. please help me fix this.

Comment: Try instead of `if (incInScore >= 10) { incInScore = 0; }`, just try `incInScore = 0;`, without any if statement. Im not sure why you do have `incInScore >= 10`, thats why it might break your code.

Comment: Nothing changes :(

Comment: Try doing the same with `if (incInScore >= 10) { oldscore = trickscore; }`, so that it would just be `oldscore = trickscore`. I would recommend logging the incInScore is throughout the script.

Comment: while (grounded == false)
        {  
            if (incInScore >= 5)
            {
            
                    multiplier = multiplier + 1;
                    incInScore = 0;
                
             }
        }
        if ( grounded == true)
        {
            multiplier = 1;            
        }

Comment: i added a hile loop but now i unity wont even start the game

Comment: ??? Your game wont run since your while loop will never end, and my best guess indicates that you see unity 'freeze'. The update function is just a function, nothing else. It is run every frame(after the iteration of the function is done), and will execute each line in order. Your while loop will never end as grounded will never change within that loop, as how would it change? The computer only does what the computer is told. Unity will keep running that loop, which will cause it to never finish the function. TLDR, your program is stuck repeating that while loop, not allowing for it to end.